# why KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP and KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN only work in ring volume event, How get event of media (music) volume using onKeyDown in android

Tags: android, onkeydown

I want to update my seekbar based on physical volume music key but my code dont work!
please help me..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        customSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
            //Do something
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            customSeekBar.setProgress(volume_level-1);
            am.adjustStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,0);

        }else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
                //Do something
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            customSeekBar.setProgress(volume_level+1);
            am.adjustStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,0);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Please try and let me know..

Comment: No, it did not work, I want to update my seekbar during playing music based on physical volume key, but when music is playing onKeyDown method dont work

Comment: Did you add seek bar max value that is android:max="15"

Comment: I set it as customSeekBar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

Comment: can you try once it from XML?

Comment: Look into your project you did minor mistake because i tested it in my demo application. It is working , If it is helpful please accept it and up vote

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> {
   audioManager?.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI)
   return true
}
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> {
   audioManager?.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI)
   return true}
```